# How to reduce one year in DateTime using update in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to reduce one year in the DateTime using update query?

```
 $result=mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE downloads SET ddtime='DATETIME_ADD('$ddtime', INTERVAL -1 YEAR)' WHERE downfile LIKE 'yark'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE downloads SET ddtime= DATE_SUB(ddtime, INTERVAL 1 Year) WHERE downfile LIKE '%yark%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

no quotes, no dollar signes:

```
UPDATE downloads SET ddtime=DATE_SUB(ddtime, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) WHERE ...
```